# How can I apply the complex formalism to calculate the time-average of a two-field product?

Tags: electromagnetism

A field $a(t)$ can be represented the following way: $$a(t)=|A_0|\cos{(\omega t-\alpha)}=Re[A_0e^{i\omega t}]=Re[A(t)],$$ where $A(t)$ is known as the complex formalism of $a(t)$. Another field $b(t)$ can be expressed similarly, with $\alpha$ replaced by $\beta$. The time-average can be calculated like so: $$<a(t)b(t)> = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T|A_0|\cos{(\omega t - \alpha)}|B_0|\cos{(\omega t - \beta)}dt.$$ I cannot for the life of me use this integral to obtain the correct result, which is $$<a(t)b(t)>=\frac{1}{2}Re[A(t)B^*(t)].$$ I have attempted using all manner of trig identities. Can anyone demonstrate how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you meant $a(t)=Re[A(t)]$ and similarly for $b(t)$, without the factor 1/2.

Direct computation shows
$$
Re[A(t)B^*(t)] =Re[|A_0|e^{i(\omega t-\alpha)}|B_0|e^{i(-\omega t+\beta)}]
=|A_0||B_0|\cos(\beta-\alpha)
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\cos{(\omega t - \alpha)}\cos{(\omega t - \beta)}dt = \frac{1}{2}\cos(\beta-\alpha)
$$
(http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+w%2F(2Pi)Cos(wt-a)Cos(wt-b)dt+from+0+to+2Pi%2Fw)
so that your identity is verified.